# Shema missing com.canonical.unity.webapps

Tags: unity, webapps

My unity tweak tool (ubuntu 15.10) stopped working after the last autoremove. Other articles suggest to run `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service` or `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common`. When trying to install it I'm getting an error message :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
   unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now looking on other questions on this forum and can't find any answer to this fix this problem. When trying to install packages that others suggest getting the same or similar error.
The same problem with package musescroe:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 musescore : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-4-2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you add the musecore ppa & then upgrade some qt5 packages?

Comment: I have installed it by ubuntu software center., and it just disappered yesterday.  I installed qt5 packages from this tutorial https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu.

Comment: Well if you are going to install different qt* packages then you'll break certain apps such as webapp-container & the repo musecore, ect. Not that different than using the musecore ppa which replaces some qt* packages & also breaks some apps. (except with the ppa you'll get a musecore built to work with replaced qt packages & an easy way to revert thru ppa-purge). So either live with the newer qt & broken stuff or go back to Ubuntu repo qt* packages.  (could be difficult depending on how you actually installed them thru that how-to, ect.

Comment: @doug I removed the qt5 packages I installed manualy, and tried with the musescore ppa but that didn't work (still missing qtbase-abi-5-4-2). I'm actually a begginer so I don't know how to install qt from repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I've added a kubuntu ppa and that was the problem. I tried to instal kde5 from a tutorial for kubuntu. Just check if you don't have something like this in your repos.